LibreOffice Impress - add margins to text highlighted area
I am trying to add some margin around the highlighted area of a text within a table cell.
Something along the line of LibreOffice presentation: wider text background, like html padding?. The problem in my case is that the text is inside a table and I cannot seem to find a way to do what's indicated in the answer.
If that is not possible, I have also thought of using the cell background, but then the problem is it will get too wide.
Basically, I have this (focus on the "About me", I am using 1 column by 2 rows table):

and I would need this instead:

As you can see, the highlighted are of the second "About me" has more margins.
Version info
Version: 6.4.7.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.9
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3;



Are you sure you want text right justified? In most English-speaking countries, that would be seen as awkward. 2. Add one or more ASCII(160), NBSP (non-breaking space) to act as a spacer.


of course not, this was just a mistake. The space is a nice solution but it solves only the horizontal padding. Since I could not find a way to add some vertical and horizontal padding to the highlighted area, I used a normal text box instead. Not ideal for my use case, but as long as I don't have a valid alternative, I can live with that.
